# Minitest fixture referencing incorrect objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  
  belongs_to :individual, optional: true
  belongs_to :union, optional: true

  has_one_attached :file
```

Upon executing a test `patch document_url(documents(:one)), params: { document: { title: documents(:two).title } }, xhr: true`  an error is returned:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Individual with 'id'=498572325
    app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:42:in `update'
```

the controller searches for the document's owner to generate an instance variable
`@individual = Individual.find(@document.individual_id)`.  A `puts`in the controller returns consistent with the error `@document.individual_id 498572325`

The fixtures for documents.yml are

```
one:
  title: MyString1
  synopsis: MyString1
  individual: individuals(:one)

two:
  title: MyString2
  synopsis: MyString3
  union: unions(:one)
```

while individuals.yml does not establish a fixed ID, leaving it to the testing environment

```
one:
  shop: shops(:one)
  categoryminor: categoryminors(:one)
  union: unions(:one)
  name_last: MyString1
  name_first: MyString1
```

in the test, before calling the update action, we verify the value of the individuals(:one).id before logging in a user and get

```
puts individuals(:one).id
==> 980190962
puts documents(:one).individual_id
==> 498572325
```

So the test result is coherent. 'individual' is not to my knowledge a [reserved word](https://devtut.github.io/rubyonrails/reserved-words.html#reserved-word-list).

Why are the test data then shifting?  Is this somehow related to Document class using ActiveStorage?

Comment: `union` is a reserved word in SQL but it shouldn't be an issue here as the table is named `unions`. ActiveRecord doesn't have a union method either but this could at some point lead to a name conflict.

Comment: should just be able to use the fixture identifier to reference it  ```individual: one``` or  ```union: one``` -- don't need to explicitly use the fixture name

Comment: To extend dbuggers comment: See https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html --> "Label references for associations" .  As the ID is generated by the name, the calculated ID from individuals(:one) is different from :one. Besides it _could_ be a good idea to give your records more explicit labels

Comment: @zaphodbin Yes, the records take on a name if there is a data-specific or edge case.  However, when I learned that most test cases only need the two base fixtures, it helped streamline thinking (and executing for testing); thus I purposely avoid it *a priori*.    That was the issue and I stand happily corrected!

Comment: @Jerome While I agree with your assessment of the AI-answer, please see [Why is it a bad idea to tell other users publicly why you believe something is (or is not) from ChatGPT (or other AI)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425578/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-tell-other-users-publicly-why-you-believe-something-is).  Note that the user started spacing out their AI-answers more today to avoid the "11 minute" problem you mentioned ;-)

Comment: That's a tough call.  It was reported & I got positive feedback.  But the answer is still out there. It is then a choice: leave a bad post there polluting matters with no comment or lay it out as an example for others.  Silence is complicity, in my book.  I do see the point of flagging with the comment however.